# Get input text without scanner

Tags: java, jcombobox, jtextfield

I work on a school project and I am now wondering if it is possible to get text from JTextField with get?

```
    // Textrutor
    JTextField textTitel = new JTextField(null, 20);
    textTitel.setToolTipText("ex. Flickan som lekte med elden");
    JTextField textSort = new JTextField(null, 10);
    textSort.setToolTipText("ex. Skräck, Action");
    JTextField textDesc = new JTextField(null, 15);
    textDesc.setToolTipText("ex. Stieg Larsson");

    // Knappar
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Lägg till");

    // Combobox
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.addItem("Film");
    comboBox.addItem("CD");
    comboBox.addItem("Bok");
    comboBox.addItem("Annat");
```

I am trying to get the text and adding it to my array like this:

```
public String getTitelText() {
    return titelText;
}

public String getDescText() {
    return descText;
}

public String getSortText() {
    return sortText;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    DatabaseTable dt = new DatabaseTable();
    dt.add(titelText, sortText, descText, descText);
```

But I think that this way is wrong, but dont know how to solve it. Another question is there any easy way to know what is selected on JComboBox?

Comment: do you want to insert a text to database table from the textfields?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want

Comment: maybe this could help  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InserttextfileintoMySQL.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.getSelectedItem();

public String getSortText() {
    return sortText.getText();
}
```

All this can easily be found in the [Java DOCs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) from SUN.

--edit-- updated my answer to really make sure you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

For JTextField use `myTextField.getText()`
For tooltip in JTextField use `myTextField.getToolTipText()`
For JComboBox use `myComboBox.getSelectedIndex()` or `myComboBox.getSelectedItem()`
First gives you the index of the selected item and he second gives you the actual item.

Comment: Thanks! But when I do it I get an error massage from eclipse "The method getText() is undefined for the type String" must I change my variable from String?

Comment: the `getText()` method is for the type `JTextField`. How are you accessing it?