# Retrieving JTextField Contents Like Scanner

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I'm trying to set up a GUI for a program of mine, and have got it mostly working. However, I would like to be able to create a method that works a lot like Scanner's nextLine(); it waits for the input from my JTextField, and then returns it. It seemed like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309629/get-input-text-without-scanner) was very similar to mine but did not wait for the user's input. Here is my GUI's current code:

```
package util;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;

public class Gui {

    public JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private final JLabel lblVector = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance().createTitle("Please type commands below.");
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Gui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void print(String text){
        textArea.append(text+"\n");
    }
    public String getInput()
    {
        String input = textField.getText();
        textField.setCaretPosition(0);
        return input;
    }
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Vector");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 720, 720);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblVector, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to call it like so:

```
String menus = gui.getInput();
```

or such; I've already set up the gui variable as a new Gui().

From my searches, I've gathered it would probably involve either a DocumentListener, or an ActionListener, or both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to the text field.  When the text field has focus and the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> an event will be fired. See [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but won't this mean that the event will be fired in actionPerformed(), and therefore not be able to be returned by my function? I am calling this function from an entirely separate file in my code.

Comment: @user1796160 : You can try this [approach](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cso39hh1efpcls/Skeleton1.java) which uses [java.beans.EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html), with the same thingy, though your said function, must take `ActionEvent` as argument and it needs to be public (I guess) for this to work.

Comment: @nIcEcOw I'm at a bit of a loss how I would actually call that from another file.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  For this case, that SSCCE needs to include both classes, so reduce the visibility of the other one to default and include it in the source of `Gui`, add a `main(String[])` and factor out the `jgoodies` dependency.

Comment: @user1796160 : Why not you simply use a `JOptionPane` or a `JDialog` for that matter, they can give you that functionality, that you craving for, if I understood your question in the right sense now. After presenting `JOptionPane/JDialog`, you can pause the flow of execution and wait for the User's input before proceeding...

Answer (score -1):

After a little bit of searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081937/java-waiting-for-some-type-of-key-press-to-continue) which answered mine:

```
public String getInput() throws InterruptedException
{
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        // Anonymous class invoked from EDT
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                latch.countDown();
            return false;
        }
    };
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
    latch.await();  // current thread waits here until countDown() is called
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
    String input = textField.getText();
    textField.setCaretPosition(0);
    return input;
}
```

Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: I had to vote this down, if only for the risk that someone else might see it and think 'this is the way to go'.  It isn't..

Comment: @AndrewThompson It works for me and none of the other alternatives presented are intelligible, so. This fulfills what I asked for.